# How to obtain the rate of VAT in Magento without order object or product

Tags: magento

I am working with Magento and I need to get the rate of VAT for the current country (France). I only have information for only the price excluding tax and sometimes the price with tax, but never both. Could you give me solutions please. thank you

PS: Excuse my broken English

For get tax rate by product:

```
 <?php
    //$_product = our product object
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore('default');
    $request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRateRequest(null, null, null, $store);
    $taxclassid = $product->getData('tax_class_id')
    $percent = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')->getRate($request->setProductClassId($taxclassid));
 ?>
```

I created a piece of code to get this rate via a order object:

```
/**
     * Get Tax Values By Order
     *
     * @param Mage_Sales_Orders_Model $order
     * @param float $amount [montant à traiter]
     * @param bool $include_tax [indique si $amount contient les taxes]
     *
     * @return array $result [tax_ratio, tax_percent , tax_amount, ttc_amount, ht_amount]
     */
    public function getTaxValuesByOrder($order,$amount,$include_tax = false){

        //On traite le montant passé en paramètre
        $amount = round(floatval($amount),3);

        //On calcule le pourcentage de la taxe
        $tax_info = $order->getFullTaxInfo();
        $tax_percent = round(floatval($tax_info[0]['percent']),2);
        $tax_coeff =100 / (100 + $tax_percent);

        if($include_tax){
            $ttc_amount = $amount;
            $ht_amount = $ttc_amount * $tax_coeff;
            $tax_amount = $ttc_amount - $ht_amount;

        }
        else{
            $ht_amount = $amount;
            $tax_amount = $ht_amount * $tax_percent / 100;
            $tcc_amount = $ht_amount + $tax_amount;
        }

        return array(
            'tax_ratio'     =>  $tax_coeff,
            'tax_percent'     =>  $tax_percent,
            'tax_amount'    =>  $tax_amount,
            'ttc_amount' =>  $ttc_amount,
            'ht_amount'     =>  $ht_amount
        );
    }
```

which returns me an array containing the conversion ratio, rate of tax, with tax amount, tax free amount and finally tax amount

Comment: Which part you want to see? I am talking about tax magento helper so I do not know what show you ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merci à tous ceux qui m'ont répondu, cependant voici la solution à mon problème.

Il suffit d'ajouter cette fonction en surcharge de tax helper:

```
/**
 *  Get current rate
 *
 * @return  float   $rate
 */
public function getCurrentRate(){
    $calc = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
    $rates = $calc->getRatesForAllProductTaxClasses($calc->getRateRequest());

    foreach ($rates as $class=>$rate) {
       $result = $rate;
    }

    return floatval($result);
}
```

To further use here is a function to add or subtract the tax:

```
/**
 * ConvertAmount
 *
 * @param   float   $amount     Amount to convert
 * @param   float   $rate       Tax rate (if NULL the rate is automatically selected)
 * @param   bool    $add_tax    Sets the direction of conversion (if true rate ($ rate) will be added, if false it will be deducted)
 *
 * @return float    $amount     Converted amount
 */
public function ConvertAmount($amount,$rate=NULL,$add_tax=true){

    if($rate == NULL)
        $rate = $this->getCurrentRate();

    $tax_coeff =100 / (100 + $rate);


    if($add_tax){
        $amount = $amount / $tax_coeff;
    }
    else{
        $amount = $amount * $tax_coeff;
    }
    return round($amount,2);
}
```